# How to create a .tar.gz file to install a custom application

Tags: software-installation, packaging, programming

I have written a simple program, and I made a `.deb` file to install it on Debian based OSs. but for other distros like Arch, I usually use a `.tar.gz` file (and doing :`./configure`, `make` and `make install`), How to make that .tar.gz file for my program ??

I can write a bash script (for example like `configure`) to copy my files to `/usr/bin/` , `/usr/share/man` and `/usr/share/doc`. so I can install my application simply by executing that script(`./configure`).
but how do other `.tar.gz` files(applications) need to run `make` and `make install` to install ???

Comment: If you don't need to build anything you don't need `make` / `make install`.

Comment: What do you mean by build ?? Is it compiling a c program ?

Comment: Arch : Use the "Arch package building tool".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To generate the application distribution archive, developer uses some tools called [GNU Autotools](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Build_System). These tools help you create the `configure` & `Makefile` which generates the distribution archive for you.

Check:

1. [Official site](https://www.gnu.org/software/) (`autogen`,`autoconf`, `automake`)
2. [Quick Tutorial](https://www.lrde.epita.fr/~adl/autotools.html)

After making the correct setup, you should be able to generate the *source archive* using:

```
make dist
```

**Notes:**

- These tools were developed primarily for use with c/c++ projects. Look for corresponding tool to use with other languages (Like Ant for Java, setup-tools for Python).
- There are also some alternatives, example for c/c++ `cmake`, `qmake` with Qt.
- A correct workflow, start with generic *source archive* `.tar.gz` then distribution specific packages like *Debian source package* and `.deb`/*Debian binary package*.